# How to remove table filter search from table - ajax with codeigniter 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, tablefilter

So I tried this tutorial : https://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-crud-modal-server-side-validation.html

and my data shows like this : [image of how the data & the features looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Z7e.png)

I just want to show the table and using the search feature on the green sign in the picture. But, when I follow the tutorial, there is some features showing (ex : red & blue sign in the picture).

Where I can change to remove the red feature in the picture and move the blue sign feature in the picture to the green sign?

I am still learning at how ajax works. Sorry if my explanation is too complicated. But, I hope you understand... Hope you can help me...

This is the function that I use at my Model - **detkelModel.php**:

```
var $table = 'detail_keluarga';
    var $column_order = array('nama', 'hubungan', 'personilid', 'lahir', null); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('nama', 'hubungan', 'personilid', 'lahir'); //set column field database for datatable searchable just nama, hubungan, personilid, lahir are searchable
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if ($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if ($i === 0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                } else {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if (count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } else if (isset($this->order)) {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if ($_POST['length'] != -1)
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
```

This is my View of the table and the searchbar - **detkel.php**:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
    <!--left navbar / Data Keluarga label-->
    <div class="col-sm-6 float-left">
        <h5>Data Keluarga Personil</h5>
    </div>
    <!-- Right navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <!-- Navbar Search, filter, plus data -->
        <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group" data-widget="search-bar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- Filter Dropdown Menu -->
        <li>
        </li>
        <!-- Plus data dropdown menu -->
        <li>
            <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="table-responsive p-0">
        <table id="table" class="table table-hover text-nowraps">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>id personil</th>
                    <th>Hubungan</th>
                    <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                    <th>Aksi</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var save_method; //for save method string
    var table;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //datatables
        table = $('#table').DataTable({
            "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
            "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
            "order": [], //Initial no order.
            // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('DetkelController/ajax_list') ?>",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            //Set column definition initialisation properties.
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [-1], //last column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            }, ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is ajax_list() in my Controller **DetkelController.php**:

```
public function ajax_list()
{
    $list = $this->dk->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    //$no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $dk) {
        //$no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $dk->nama;
        $row[] = $dk->hubungan;
        $row[] = $dk->personilid;
        $row[] = $dk->lahir;

        //add html for action
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person(' . "'" . $dk->id . "'" . ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person(' . "'" . $dk->id . "'" . ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->dk->count_all(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->dk->count_filtered(),
        "data" => $data,
    );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: Those are default features of the `DataTable` JS plugin. You can configure features wanted in the options object (see docs). You would then also need to write a custom search for the one you create in green

Comment: @charlietfl could you please share a references link? because I don't really understand how to make custom table filter from the docs...

Comment: @charlietfl should I change the 'search' from if ($_POST['search']['value']) at my Model?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()